# Copying contents of a text file into a buffer (win32api)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text-files

I have some data in a text file. Now I want to copy this data to a character buffer so that I can send it iver a udp socket. How can I copy the data in a text file to a buffer?
I have tried fread for this purpose but it also copies some of the redundant data, though I have specified only the number of bytes equal to the file size to be read, still it is reading some redundant data.
Below is code snippet that I am trying:

```
    char file_buffer[1000];
    fpSend = fopen("sendclInformation.txt", "w+");
    WriteFile(sendFile,"Data in File",strlen("Data in File"),&dwWritten,0);
    fseek(fpSend, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t file_size = ftell(fpSend); // The size calculated here is 12 so fread must display only 12 bytes but it is displaying large redundant data appended to actual data.
    fseek(fpSend, 0, SEEK_SET);                         
    if(file_size>0)   //if file size>0
    {  
    int bytes_read=0;                               
if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, file_size, 1, fpSend))<=0)
    {                                                                                        "Unable to copy file into buffer",
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox( NULL,file_buffer,"File copied in Buffer",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you open a file in text mode then fseek/fread doesn't work properly.

Comment: what should I try then? :(

Comment: You should open the file for reading, not writing, if you intend to read from it! `fpSend = fopen("sendclInformation.txt", "r");` should work better.

Comment: But I want to read+write from/to my file :(

Comment: Then use "r+b" in fopen - it's read/write (r+) and binary mode (b)

Comment: still does not work  :(

Answer (score 0):

## issue

you write the the string but seem not to write the ending \0 to mark the end of the string, still when you read from the file you seem to assume that it is a proper terminated string that you get so

### change

```
WriteFile(sendFile,"Data in File",strlen("Data in File"),&dwWritten,0);
```

to

```
WriteFile(sendFile,"Data in File",strlen("Data in File") + 1,&dwWritten,0);
```

## other

Open the file in r/w binary mode using `"wb+"` this will ensure that what you read/write from/to the file is raw bytes without any newline conversions. If you open the file in text mode the `fseek` and `ftell` will give wrong (for your purposes) results.

Your if statement seems a bit weird, maybe you meant instead of

```
if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, file_size, 1, fpSend))<=0)
{
  "Unable to copy file into buffer",
}
else
{
  MessageBox( NULL,file_buffer,"File copied in Buffer",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
}
```

something like this (*note also that I changed the fread arguments*)

```
if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, 1, file_size, fpSend))<file_size)
{
  MessageBox( NULL,"error","Unable to copy file into buffer",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
}
else
{
  MessageBox( NULL,file_buffer,"File copied in Buffer",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
}
```

It is also recommended that you check for